# recursive method max depth- static variable

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, recurrence

i want to get the maximum depth of an XML file using a recursive method firstly i have declared the variable

```
 public static int maxdepth=0;

 private static void GetDepth(NodeList nl, int level,int maxdepth) {      

   level++;
   if (maxdepth<level)
   {
       maxdepth= level;
   }
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nl.item(i);
            if (n instanceof Element)
            {            
            GetDepth(n.getChildNodes(), level, maxdepth);
            }
        }

    }

}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  NodeList nl = root.getChildNodes();
  GetDepth(nl,level,maxdepth);
  System.out.println(maxdepth);
 }
```

and when i would display the value of variable maxdepth, I receive the value 0, as the declaration

Comment: You have two variables both named maxdepth, so in your first method when you say maxdepth = level, you are only affecting the variable that's declared in your methods arguements, not the actual field you have declared in your class.

Comment: On a side note, instead of doing level++, a more common practice to increment level in a recursive function is pass level+1 at the recursive call:  GetDepth(n.getChildNodes(), level+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as a one-liner using XPath 2.0:

```
max(for $n in //* return count($n/ancestor::*))
```

Even in Java, you're making it much more difficult than it is:

```
public int maxDepth(Node node) {
  int max = 0;
  NodeList kids = node.getChildNodes();
  if (kids.getLength() == 0) {
     return 0;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<kids.getLength(); i++) {
     int kidMax = maxDepth(kids.item(i);
     if (kidMax > max) max = kidMax;
  }
  return max + 1;
}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 4):

You `int maxdepth` in the method signature of `getDepth` is hiding the static variable `maxdepth`. Delete it from the signature:

`private static void GetDepth(NodeList nl, int level)`

then the method will work.

Answer (score 1):

At this code part :

```
if (maxdepth<level)
{
    maxdepth= level;
}
```

You are updating the local variable maxdepth instead of the static variable. Giving a different name to one of the variables will make it work but since maxdepth parameter of the method is unnecessary I'd just remove it.